# Angular: Access an external static class inside of a components template

Tags: angular, typescript

Lets say I have an angular component with the corresponding class.

```
@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: `       whatever    `
})

export class TestComponent
{}
```

And then I have a class with static members (bound to the class and not to an instance).

```
export class Config
{
    public static foo () : string
    {  return "blabla"; }
}
```

Is there a way I can call Config.foo in the template of my component?

```
template: ` {{ Config.foo () }} `
```

It works if I wrap it inside TestComponent and call that in my component.

```
template: `{{ myfoo () }}`
...
export class TestComponent
{
  myfoo ()
  { return Config.foo (); }
}
```

But thats not what I want.

Config should hold global config information and I do not want to wrap any piece of info in a lot of components.

Or is there some more elegant way? I thought about injection (singleton) but I would prefer the static way more for stateless constant information.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use "global" service (provided in main module) and pass variables across components by it, also as reference to them.

So, in the constructor you should inject service, as public property, and then in the view `{{ myServiceInstance.myPropOrFnCall }}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal that you cannot call your `Config.foo` method inside the template.

Inside a template, expressions inside double brackets (`{{}}`) are "scoped" to the component itself: `this` is implictly put on expressions.

The thing I use often in this case are "getters", like this:

```
get configFoo(): string { return Config.foo(); }
```

Inside the template, it looks like this:

```
{{configFoo}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Static mambers are not directly accessible at html templates. These mambers are just used to create singl-tone object and direct access to other classes. So we have to create a non static method to return it's value at html templates. Templates are bounded with "this", which is associated class to that template.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your component:

```
export class TestComponent {
  // Creates a property on your component called Config, which is a reference to the Config class.
  Config = Config;
}
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{{ Config.foo() }}
```